# Handling binary file -Display garbage

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles

In order to practice how to handling binary file, I create a small program that can `add`, `update`, and `tell` us which element are in a binary file. (In my case there are random numbers). When I run my code the file is created and there is no runtime error, but it display garbage and not random numbers like I want. I don't understand through the debugger which function is not implemented correctly.
Can you help me find where is the problem in order to correct my code.

```
template <class T>
class VectorFile
{
    string fname;
    fstream data;
    int size;
public:
    VectorFile(const string& fn);
    ~VectorFile();
    void add(const T& elem);
    T getAt(int pos);
    void setAt(int pos, const T& elem);
    int getSize() const { return this->size; }
};

template<class T>
VectorFile<T>::VectorFile(const string& fn) : fname(fn)
{
    ofstream fs;
    fs.open(fname, ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!fs)
        throw "error while opening file";
    fs.seekp(0, ios::end);
    int end = fs.tellp();
    size = end / sizeof(T);
    fs.clear();
}

template <class T>
VectorFile<T>::~VectorFile()
{
    data.close();
}

template <class T>
void VectorFile<T>::add(const T& elem)
{
    data.seekp((size - 1) * sizeof(T), ios::beg);
    data.write((char*)&elem, sizeof(T));
}
template <class T>
T VectorFile<T>::getAt(int pos)
{
    T elem;
    data.seekg((pos - 1) * sizeof(T), ios::beg);
    data.read((char*)&elem, sizeof(T));
    return elem;
}

template <class T>
void VectorFile<T>::setAt(int pos, const T& elem)
{
    data.seekp((pos - 1) * sizeof(T));
    data.write((char*)&elem, sizeof(T));
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    try
    {
        VectorFile<int> vf("f1.dat");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            vf.add(rand() % 100);
        for (int i = 0; i < vf.getSize(); i++)
            cout << vf.getAt(i) << "\t";
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            vf.setAt(i * 2, i);
        for (int i = 0; i < vf.getSize(); i++)
            cout << vf.getAt(i) << "\t";
    }
    catch (char const* msg)
    {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I edit my constructor thanks to comment but this also doesn't work. Please tell me what's wrong with this.

```
VectorFile<T>::VectorFile(const string& fn) : fname(fn), data(fname, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc)
{
    if (!data)
        throw "Error while opening file";
}
```

Comment: If you're dealing with binary data you should use `std::ios::binary` accordingly when opening the file.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann I read on web that if `data.write` function is like I write compiler know that it's binary file. I correct this but still I have same problem

Comment: @Ronyco123 You read wrong. `data.write` does write raw bytes to a file, but if that file is not opened in binary mode on Windows you're subject to line ending translation and incorrect EOF detection.

Comment: Where are you opening `data`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think in the constructor

Comment: Can you point to a line of code where `data` is opened? I can't. You declare a member, and it gets default constructed. In the constructor you have a local variable that opens a file, but that will not cause `data` to be an open file.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm See my new constructor I edit it, so that I think data is opened.  It create the file, but display only garbage